# Insert highest absolut value filtered by category into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to select the highest absolute value from a table for every category.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
     CategoryID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
     ExpValue   INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (11, 0);
INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (11, 11);
INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (11, -59);
INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (130, 0);
INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (130, 59);
INSERT INTO mytable (CategoryID, ExpValue) VALUES (130, -2);
```

Which turns to this

```
+------------+----------+
| CategoryID | ExpValue |
+------------+----------+
|         11 |        0 |
|         11 |      -13 |
|         11 |      -59 |
|        130 |        0 |
|        130 |       59 |
|        130 |        2 |
+------------+----------+
```

For every category, I select the top value like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Result
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #SmallTable
    WHERE CategoryID = 11
    ORDER BY ExpValue DESC;
```

This works pretty good. But I know found out about an edge case. As you can see for `CategoryID = 11`, it would return the row with 0.

But I would like it to pick the value -59 instead. So the highest `abs()` from any number.

And for `CategoryID = 130`, it should pick 59 as a row.

There can only be 3 cases for the table.

1. For the specific `CategoryID` where multiple positive values and a 0 value exists -> return the highest value
2. For a specific `CategoryID` where multiple 0 values exist -> pick one 0 value
3. For a specific `CategoryID` where multiple negative values and a 0 value exist -> pick the lowest value.

As you can see there is always a fallback with 0 present but other than the only positive only negative or no other values at all.

The table in fact has many more columns (30) but I only showed the 2 which are needed for the query. But in fact I need to take the whole row.

The result for my example table should be:

```
+------------+----------+
| CategoryID | ExpValue |
+------------+----------+
|         11 |      -59 |
|        130 |       59 |
+------------+----------+
```

Edit: thanks everyone. I ended up doing it like this:

```
INSERT INTO #Result
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #SmallTable
    WHERE CategoryID = 11
    ORDER BY ABS(ExpValue) DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option. Use the `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function in the `ORDER BY` clause, along with `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  CategoryID,
  ExpValue
FROM
  mytable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY ABS(ExpValue) DESC);
```

Results:

```
+------------+----------+
| CategoryID | ExpValue |
+------------+----------+
|         11 |      -59 |
|        130 |       59 |
+------------+----------+
```

It's easier to see how this works by putting the row numbers into the select list:

```
  CategoryID,
  ExpValue,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ORDER BY ABS(ExpValue) DESC) as RowNum
FROM
  mytable;
```

Results:

```
+------------+----------+--------+
| CategoryID | ExpValue | RowNum |
+------------+----------+--------+
|         11 |      -59 |      1 |
|         11 |       11 |      2 |
|         11 |        0 |      3 |
|        130 |       59 |      1 |
|        130 |       -2 |      2 |
|        130 |        0 |      3 |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` just takes the number 1 row from each grouping.

Here's a [Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZQGM4604).

Comment: Yup. Here's a [Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZQGM4604).

Comment: I ended up doing it like this: INSERT INTO #Result
 Select TOP 1 *
 FROM #SmallTable
 WHERE CategoryID=11
 ORDER BY abs(ExpValue) DESC;

Is ther anything wrong with it? Because you do it quite different.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query. The way I wrote it, it gets all of the groupings at once. You're getting them one at a time. Just a different approach.

Comment: Ah ok. Thats much smarter. I will look at it later again and implement it when i understand it fully. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery for amx abs(

```
select  m.CategoryID, m.ExpValue
from #SmallTable m
INNER JOIN  (
    Select CategoryID , max(abs(ExpValue )) max_abs
    FROM #SmallTable
    GROUP BY CategoryID

    ) t on t.max_abs = abs(ExpValue )
        and t.CategoryID = m.CategoryID
```

.

```
INSERT INTO #Result
select  m.CategoryID, m.ExpValue
from #SmallTable m
INNER JOIN  (
    Select CategoryID , max(abs(ExpValue )) max_abs
    FROM #SmallTable
    GROUP BY CategoryID

    ) t on t.max_abs = abs(ExpValue )
        and t.CategoryID = m.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single aggregation and some conditional logic:

```
select categoryid,
       (case when abs(min(expval)) > abs(max(expval)) then min(expval)
             else max(expval)
        end)
from #smalltable
group by categoryid;
```

If you only want this for one category, you can filter before the `group by`.